# Is it possible to do swap, start, stop slots in cloud service classic, on azure devops?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell

I do ci/cd to **Cloud Service(classic)** with **azure devops**. I have steps like **start** or **stop** and **swap** slots in this Cloud Service. I thought I can use **PowerShell** for these goals. 
In the beginning, I tried Azure PowerShell job. Unfortunately, I have not found the required commands in **Az** and **azureRM** modules.
So I decided to use just PowerShell job, where I install the Azure module and I want to use these commands `Start-AzureService` and `Stop-AzureService`. Is it the right way? Or is there something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in principle that would be true, however you can use the ARM proxy provider (`Microsoft.ClassicCompute`) for that:

```
Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup `
    -ResourceType 'Microsoft.ClassicCompute/domainNames/slots' `
    -ResourceName $cloudService/$slotName `
    -ApiVersion '2018-06-01' -Action 'Stop' -Force
```

I don't have a working cloud service to test this, but should be close enough